# USDT transfer at BTC address from binance exchange

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I am transfer USDT to BTC address by mistake but since last 3 month USDT missing .how I will take back in my account.
  Binance not help me for get back my USDT.or BTC. They r saying when your transection abnormal or cancel you contact us.since last 3 month I am reading these by binance.

Answer (score 0):

The btc address you transferred the coins to, does it belong to you or binance? If it is yours, then you can be able to recover it without needing binance.